# strange urls in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

The Zend project creates URLs like:
http://localhost/zftest/public/index/add

How can I have a URL like 
http://localhost/zftest/add.php

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you seem to be after getting rid of the "public" part. There are two ways to it.

First, the .htaccess. In the project's root directory, create two files: `index.php` and `.htaccess`, with the following contents:

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

index.php:

```
<?php 
define('RUNNING_FROM_ROOT', true);
include 'public/index.php';
```

And there you have it, no "public" in the URL.

The other way to achieve it is by setting up a domain. You'll need to modify two files: `hosts` and `httpd-vhosts.conf`. The hosts file is located at `/etc/hosts` under Linux or in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` under Windows. Both need root level access. Just add the line

```
127.0.0.1 zftest.local
```

Then find your vhosts file. I'm using XAMPP, so here are the paths to it for XAMPP: `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` under Windows, `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`. Just add something like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot              /opt/lampp/htdocs/zftest/public
    ServerName                zftest.local
    ServerAlias               zftest.local
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV    development
    SetEnv APPLICATION_DOMAIN zftest.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, when you go to `zftest.local` (choose any name you wish, of course), you'll see your front page, no "public" part in the URL.

As for the other part of the question, you need a custom router. Setting up a router is really easy and you can find lots of information about on the internet. Some prefer to do it in the bootstrap, but I believe the easiest way is to do it in the application.ini file. Here's a sample router:

```
resources.router.routes.getbyroute.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
resources.router.routes.getbyroute.route = "(.+)\.php"
resources.router.routes.getbyroute.defaults.controller = index
resources.router.routes.getbyroute.defaults.action = index
resources.router.routes.getbyroute.map.1 = action
resources.router.routes.getbyroute.reverse = "%s.php"
```

This should take care of your route (in theory, I haven't tested it for correctness, hehe). Investigate routers though, as you'll probably want something more generic than this (this one won't handle other controllers than `index`).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem with the default Zend routes as that style of URL mapping is considered a good practice (SEO friendly, clear mapping from URLs to modules, controllers and actions), but if you want to change the routing you should read up on the [Zend Controller Router Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html). Then your mapping might e.g. look like this:

```
<?php

$router = $frontController->getRouter();
$router->addRoute(
    'add',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('add.php', array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'add'))
);

?>
```

Comment: The OP can also lose the "public" part in the URL by setting the document root to `path/to/zftest/public` directory

Answer (score 0):

This is normally accomplished by using Virtual Host document root, or more commonly by dropping in an .htacess file to redirect all requests to your /public/index.php.

See http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Configuring+Your+URL+Rewriter for more details.